# how to force runuser to initiate an interactive shell the same way `bash -i` is used?

Tags: bash, users, root, interactive

I need to run the following command as `mruser` as root

`systemctl --user status myservice`

To do this I use runuser

`runuser -l mruser -c "systemctl --user status myservice"`

This works perfectly fine in my RHEL deployments but fails in Ubuntu. This is because the default `.bashrc` file for Ubuntu has the following line (Which RHEL .bashrc files do not):

```
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

This makes bash require `-i` to be interactive and use values in the `.bashrc` file. If I remove these lines then my `runuser` command runs fine on Ubuntu. I dont want to have to remove these lines though.

How can I make `runuser` send a `-i` when running its commands?

Comment: maybe as a workaround, you can leverage `.profile`; see https://askubuntu.com/a/1468012/132098